# 'href' attribute does not work in <a> tag when i want to perform javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, django-templates, jinja2

i use django(version 3.1.6) with html5, when i want to perform any link in 'a' tag and also execute a function from 'script' in 'button' tag ,nothing happen with clicking the link text. but unusually the link works fine if i remove function execution part from onclick attribute in button tag. this is the code i have in my home.html (template):

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
   <tr>
<td>
<button class="rounded" type="button" id="btn1" onclick='my_function(`{{ object_from_classbasedview }}`)'>
<a href="some url here">
Click me!
</a>
</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<text id='txt1'></text>
</body>

<script>
function my_function(param1){
event.PreventDefault();
document.getElementById('txt1').innerHtml=param1;
}
</script>
</html>
```

i Tried many solutions but none of them worked. Any idea or solution appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Having a link inside of a button is semantically strange, and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Why not just have either a link *or* a button (styled to look like whatever you want) which performs both operations?  What's the overall goal?

Comment: A `<button>` cannot contain any interactive content, such as `<a>`.

Comment: @David thankyou for guide david, your right , it should be either button or a , but i need both , cause i cant execute the function from 'a' tag , or make link with 'button'(according to what i learned)however its possible with some tricks!  But a overall goal : i want to redirect user in a webpage, and then get some information from database and present that on this webpage, all the things by clicking this button.

Comment: @alishokrollahi: *"cause i cant execute the function from 'a' tag"* - Yes you can, by handling its `click` event in JavaScript.  *"or make link with 'button'"* - Yes you can, but redirecting the user in JavaScript in the button's `click` handler.  *"i want to redirect user in a webpage, and then get some information from database and present that on this webpage"* - Then what you want is simply a link.  Just link to the page that you want the user to go to.  You seem to be overcomplicating this by involving a button at all.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the `onClick` trigger is having priority here. If you put the `a` tag outside the button the same would happen with `href`.

A solution could be to only use the onClick function (remove `href` altogether) and do the redirect inside said function.

your function would end up looking something like this:

```
function my_function(param1){
    event.PreventDefault();
    document.getElementById('txt1').innerHtml=param1;
    window.location.href = "some url here";
}
```